# Centralise Apache log for all 404 errors to separate file (for all domains)?

Tags: apache-2.4, logging, log-files

Is it possible to configure the Apache log **for all domains** into **one single** centralised file, **besides** the normal log files (those i want as-well).

I would even prefer for only 404 (access), so single log file for all domains and only 404 messages (while keeping the log files that are setup in each virtual domain)?

UPDATE 1:
access log files

UPDATE 2:
I'm looking for a config option for server wide, i don't want to adjust each config. And the message should be logged in both domain access log **and** the main log.

Comment: Do you refer to access.log 404 entries, or are you refering to error.log?

Comment: @ezra-s good point, i'm taking about the access log files

Comment: I would check the info regarding conditional logging at [conditional logging at the httpd official docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/logs.html#conditional).

Answer (score 1):

The CustomLog directive has an `env=` parameter, which can be added at the end. It can then be set with the help of `mod_rewrite`. The configuration file should contain something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
# exclude directory index
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index\.(php|html?)$
# exlcude auto-index of directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
# if the request is not a file, directory, or symlink
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
# set the "notfound" environment variable
RewriteRule ^ - [E=notfound:true,L]

CustomLog /var/log/apache2/404-requests.log common env=notfound
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/requests.log common env=!notfound
```

The custom log file `404-requests.log` will log events only when the `notfound` environment is set, while the log `requests.log` will log everything else.

Comment: @dimiar yeah. Thats what i was afraid off. per domain config stuff. Not what i am looking for :(

Answer (score 0):

I take it each VirtualHost has its own logging directives? If so, they overwrite any global directives.

To have a global access log, you'd need to remove or modify the logging directives from the virtual host configurations.

Comment: Yeah, and thats the problem i should described it a bit better, will update the question.